# Database Restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL 2012

I am  trying to restore a Full Backup Database in my local computer. Backup has been taken from a Server Database. I tried both wizard option as well as syntax option.

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB_Backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

On executing the above syntax , I am getting error message as follows.

Error Message says that, Original backup file - .mdf and .ldf is still mapped to the original server path.

```
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
File 'DB_Backup_Data' cannot be restored to 'D:\My Path\Data\DB_Backup.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
File 'DB_Backup_Log' cannot be restored to 'D:\My Path\Data\DB_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
```

How to remap the .ldf and .mdf to my local computer and restore the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB_Backup.bak'
WITH MOVE 'MyDatabase_Data' TO 'D:\My Path\Data\DB_Backup.mdf',
MOVE 'MyDatabase_Log' TO 'D:\My Path\Data\DB_log.ldf',
REPLACE
```

Also check [DB Restoration Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b58cdcf-b27c-4b7e-a09a-9d4136c98bb0/db-restoration-problem?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct SQL server to move the files to their correct location on your local machine - something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB_Backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
    MOVE 'DB_Data' TO 'C:\MyData\MyDatabase_Data.mdf', 
    MOVE 'DB_Log' TO 'C:\MyLog\MyDatabase_Log.ldf'
```

You need to substitute the correct logical file names in for DB_Data and DB_Log and the correct physical file names for the database on your local machine for the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Restore Database..** then add your `.bak` file you want to restore.
After that go to **Options** and change **Restore As** path 
[image]